# cordova/phonegap : cannot connect to socket.io

Tags: cordova, socket.io, intel-xdk

My application works fine on browser.

When I compile it with intelXDL / phonegap : AJAX calls works fine, but not socket.io connections. (sockets use port 1445)

I have

> "status: cancelled"

so it looks like permissions problem

[image: permissions problems]

I tried to add ALL possible combinations for whitelist (I use CLI 4.1.2)

```
    http://www.example.com/*
    http://www.example.com:1445/*
    http://*:1445/*
    http://*
    *
```

The first rule makes AJAX call possible. The other rules do not allow to connect to socket.io on port 1445

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

@yarek,
This is a canned answer because Cordova just move the documentation, without warning or announcement.

### The fix to many common *white-list* problems

The alternative is this quick fix – but know that this *quick fix* removes all needs for `white-list`. This creates a [security issue](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-webview-security-582363/) which you may not want to by pass.

**QUICK FIX** Add this to your `config.xml`  for **PHONEGAP BUILD ONLY**
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`

The long answer is as such:

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1 and cli-5.2.0. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let's say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. **Depending on your use and the version of Phonegap you are using, the CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. However, there are cases where it is not needed at all. The documentation is confusing for some, please read it carefully.** The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)

Comment: Great help. Unfortunatlly I have already played with all that and have fixed the ajax calls thanks to this guid. But no way to fix sokcet.io connection. Don't you have a working phonegpa project or sample that uses socket.io ?

Comment: You can try using the websocket URI. It is `ws://` Google: [websocket url](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket+url). This looks like a good example: *Websocket.org | [Echo test](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html)* If you are still having problems, write back - I'll work on an example for you. Best of Luck